# Insert data into SQLite but getting KeyError - Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to insert data into database but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "business.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = fetch_data(con)
  File "business.py", line 18, in fetch_data
   result.append((entry['address'], entry['postalcode'],
KeyError: 'address'
```

Still new to python and coding. Appreciate your help, folks!

What I have so far:

```
import requests
import sqlite3

URL = 'http://url/url/url/{}.json'
def fetch_data(con):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT identifier FROM restaurant WHERE res_creditnote = 'No' LIMIT 6")
    result = []
    for row in cur:
        r = requests.get(URL.format(row[0]))
        entry = r.json()
        result.append((entry['address'], entry['postalcode'],
                       entry['postal'], entry['statenumber'], entry['state'],
                       entry['countrycode'], entry['country']))
    return result

con = sqlite3.connect("business.db")
data = fetch_data(con)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO hotel (address, postalcode, '
                'postal, statenumber, state, '
                'countrycode, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', data)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

---

**EDIT**

I try to fetch json data like this:

```
"businessaddress":{"address":"Stockholm road 11","postalcode":"045432","postal":"Stockholm","statenumber":"45141","state":"Stockholm","countrycode":"SW","country":"Sweden"}
```

Comment: What are you confused about? The error is telling you that the JSON you have downloaded does not contain an "address" key.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please, see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data appears to a dictionary containing a key "businessaddress" which itself is a dictionary containing the other keys. So you need to access it that way, either via `entry['businessaddress']['address']` etc or by assigning the inner dictionary to a temporary variable and using that:

```
entry = r.json()['businessaddress']
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! Do you have time to chat in a private room? I have a few other important questions I really want to ask you about. I do not know how to invite you to a private chat. That is if you are available, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with SQL, but with your dictionary called `entry`. Apparently the JSON you're retrieving does not have a address key in it. You can try debugging by printing then entry dictionary after this line `entry = r.json()`